# WorkItem Migrator tool from TFS to Azure

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, migration

I am trying to import a work Item from TFS to Azure and I want all the link types associated with the work Item to be imported in Azure. we have lot of custom fields and links in TFS. What can I do if the link type exists in TFS but does not exist in Azure. Can I do any mapping like how we do for field mappings.

For example in TFS , I have a User story implements (link type) a spec but in Azure I want to use User story references (link type) a spec.

So when I am importing a user story with specs linked to it and link type 'implement' it should convert it to 'references' when it imports. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi maryam, Does jessehouwing's answer help? Please check it and kindly let us know the result. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the [Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/), and create a mapping configuration specifying the from/to of work item types, fields and relations.

You'll probably need to build a [WorkItemLinkEnricher](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/EndpointEnrichers/) to map from one link type to another.

You could also do an as-is import of the project collection and leave it in XML mode, that way the existing links will migrate over, but you won't have all the advantages of the new Process Model in Azure DevOps.